# telegraf enum plugin not injecting the correct destination field

Tags: telegraf

I have the following telegraf configurations:

```
[[inputs.http_response]]
name_override="test"
address="https://localhost:12345/test"
response_timeout="5s"
method="GET"
follow_redirects=false
insecure_skip_verify = true
response_string_match="test is up"
 [inputs.http_response.tags]
    system="system"
    component="component"
[[processors.enum]]
 [[processors.enum.mapping]]
    field = "result_type"
    dest = "value"
   [processors.enum.mapping.value_mappings]
     success = 1
```

And i get the following response:

```
test,component=component,system=system result_type="success" 1611588662000000000
```

I was anticipating

```
test,component=component,system=system result_type="success",value=1i 1611588662000000000
```

What am i doing incorrectly here? I'm using version `1.9.2` and it shows it has the plugin.